# SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, visual-studio-2013

I have seen a lot similar questions like this on Stackoverflow that has been closed, but I hope that there is a solution to my question.

My T-SQL code is following:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].AccountItem
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [AccountId] INT NOT NULL, 
    [ItemId] INT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT [AccountFK] FOREIGN KEY (AccountId) REFERENCES Accounts(Id), 
    CONSTRAINT [ItemFK] FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES Item(Id)
)
```

And my error(s):

```
Error   2   SQL46010: Incorrect syntax near ).  dbo.Table   3   1   
Error   1   SQL80001: Incorrect syntax near ')'.    dbo.Table   3   1
```

I've seen on other's threads where it says "Change the 'Target Platform'" but I can't find that section in my project properties.

I have VS2013 for Windows Desktop.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are those tables you refer to in your foreign key constraints available? And do they indeed have a primary key on that column you reference?

Comment: Right click on the document and select SQLCMD mode - [source](http://geekswithblogs.net/tonyt/archive/2010/03/05/138363.aspx). Also check the comments for that post, added comments for VS2012 versions

Comment: I had forgotten to set a primary key on the referenced column. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AccountItem](
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[AccountId] [int] NOT NULL,
[IitemsId] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Table_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
[id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,         

ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY],
CONSTRAINT [AccountFK] FOREIGN KEY (AccountId) REFERENCES Accounts(Id), 
CONSTRAINT [ItemFK] FOREIGN KEY (ItemId) REFERENCES Item(Id)
) ON [PRIMARY]
```